# Excel: Remember Text to Columns Setting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a fixed width format text file that I need to convert to an Excel spreadsheet.

I know how to use Text to Columns and that's no problem. The problem is that I will need to do this multiple times to different files over a period of time. Is there a way to store/save/remember the column widths so I don't have to enter it every time?

Answer (score 2):

When you perform Text-to-Columns, do it with the macro Recorded switched on.  This will create a macro that can be re-played anytime you want.

[image]